# How to make dynamic section in a single page website using pyroCMS like pages of PyroCMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, pyrocms

Actually i have gone through lot of google pages, but still didn't find the exact solutions. I have got the single page website theme. I am trying to make it dynamic using PyroCMS. From the admin panel we have got "page" and "navigation" to manage the pages of the site. But in the case of single page website, there is different section like About, Services, etc. Now i want to know, how can i control the different section of the same page using pyrocms. 
Should I need to make the new modules for sections or ...?

My .Htmls file code snippet is:

```
 <section class="about_area scrollto" id="about">
 .....
 </section>
<section class="service_area" id="services">
 .....
 </section>
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a custom Page Type (http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/getting-started/creating-a-page-type).
You'll have to create 2 Page Type: 1 that represents a section and 1 that represents the actual page, that combines all the sections.

For example:

create a Page Type section called "SinglePageSections" with a field "body" (WYSIWYG field type or a html-only textarea, probably with tags enabled).

Create an additional field called "section_css_class", to add the neccessary classes to the section - and of course additional fields if the section needs anything more, like for example the "id".

I recommend to create a field for everything you need, so you wont have to mess with html attributes in the "body" field.

You don't have to do anything in the layout tab.

Then create a page type called "SinglePage". This will combine all it's child pages into a single page.

Enter the following code in the "Layout" tab of this page type:

```
{{ pages:children id=page:id }}
  {{ customfields }}
    <section class="{{ section_css_class }}">
      {{ body }}
    </section>
  {{ /customfields }}
{{ /pages:children }}
```

This will pick up all the child pages of your "SinglePage"-page.

In the "Pages" admin, you can now create a new page based on the "SinglePage" Page Type and add as many child pages of "SinglePageSection" to it as you like. Each of those child pages will be picked up by the tags in the "SinglePage" layout, and it's content will be rendered into the section html tags.
This way you can rearrange the sections, disable them by setting them to "draft" etc.

Hope that helps you!